# MVC Annotation [Range(m, n)] does not prevent entering text

Tags: c#, annotations, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model with the following field:

```
[Range(0, 100)]
public int? Points { get; set; }
```

I display the field with auto-generated code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Points, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Points)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Points)
    </div>
</div>
```

If the user enters a number outside of the range he is greeted with an appropriate message. Also, if the user leaves the field empty, I get the expected behavior: the field is set to `null`.

But if the user enters some string that doesn't parse as valid integer, the input accepts this happily and assigns `null` to the property `Points`. To me, this was a very unexpected behavior.

How can I limit the input to either empty or valid integer in the range?

Comment: Actually that *is* the expected behavior. Your model state will be invalid and you'll have the error in the model state errors collection. If you require a value, add the `Required` attribute to the model property.

Comment: It's not silent - check `ModelState.IsValid` and `ModelState.Errors` as I suggested. The model binder is failing when it attempts to parse the textbox into into a valid `int?`

Comment: My ModelState.IsValid is true, and there are no errors?